# How can I store each separate entire line in a text file into an array?

Tags: grep, array, cut

I have a file called "threewords". It contains the information:

```
\#gray speedy bee

gr-A | sp-E-d-E | b-E

\#gray greedy pea

gr-A | gr-E-d-E | p-E
```

When I run the command:

```
cat threewords | grep ^# | cut -c2-
```

The command pulls the two lines beginning with #. It then removes the # and returns this as output:

```
gray speedy bee

gray greedy pea
```

When I run my command:

```
array=($(cat threewords | grep ^# | cut -c2-))
```

It creates the array but it separates all the words into separate array positions like this:

```
array[0] = gray,
array[1] = speedy,
array[2] = bee,
array[3] = gray,
array[4] = greedy,
array[5] = pea
```

I can figure out the code to make it put the output of each line into an array like so:

```
array[0] = gray speedy bee, 
array[1] = gray greedy pea
```

Comment: this is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

The splitting is done with `IFS` as the delimiter (which contains a space, newline and tab by default). Set the `IFS` to only the newline:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' a=($(printf "1 2\n2 3\n"))
$ echo ${a[0]}
1 2
$ echo ${a[1]}
2 3
```

This will change `IFS` for the shell, so best save it before and restore it:

```
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n' array=($(grep '^#' threewords | cut -c2-))
IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

And there's absolutely no reason to do:

```
cat threewords | grep '^#'
```

`grep` is perfectly capable of reading files:

```
grep '^#' threewords
```

As [Stephane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174111/how-can-i-store-each-seperate-entire-line-in-a-text-file-into-an-array/174112?noredirect=1#comment287430_174112) notes, when subjecting the output of a command to further shell expansion, one should disable globbing using `set -f`:

```
$ help set 
...
      -f  Disable file name generation (globbing).
```

Otherwise:

```
$ cd /; a=( $(printf "*\n") )
$ echo ${a[@]}
bin boot cdrom dev etc home ...
```

Comment: You also need `set -f`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `bash` 4

```
mapfile -t array < <(grep ^# threewords | cut -c2-)
```

Will populate `array`, one line per element

```
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
gray speedy bee
gray greedy pea
```